# BlackBerry Storm - Cannot scroll vertically while in TreeField

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I am having issues performing a vertical scroll on the BlackBerry Storm while in a TreeField.

The tree nodes expand just fine, even with expanded nodes while in the tree I cannot scroll to the bottom of the expanded list. Sometimes it will scroll a little but then not allow me to scroll back up.

Could this be an issue with the screen not being a fixed size?

The TreeField is in a VeriticalFieldManager with the VERTICAL_SCROLL and VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR styles.

The screen I am using is MainScreen.

Comment: Hi! I can't reproduce issue with 8 child nodes and scroll on Bold 9000. Can you give more details? Sample code, device model, screenshot would be helpful!

Comment: I was able to figure it out. The developer captured the touchEvent and returned false for the entire screen, which disallows scrolling on the screen. I moved the touchEvent code inside the TreeField and that resolved the issue. The touchEvent code was there in order to prevent issues with the tree expanding and collapsing immediately upon being touched. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: you should add this as an answer to you own question.